# how to drill down a tableview using coredata without fetchresultscontroller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, storyboard, segue

i have a table view in the first screen i click on the add button n go add details there (first name ,last name and age) and save. Its saved n gets me to the parent screen,den wen i click on the accessory indicator i want to go the same view n see those details of my selected row in those text fields. Im using segue's n passing the object, the object is passed but i dont see it in the textfields ,i get a the screen with empty textfields.thanks showing the code below:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {

     if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddNew"])


    {
          addNewController = segue.destinationViewController;

           addNewController.delegate = self;

}
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowRow"])
{
    NSIndexPath *pathChosen = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;


    personObject = [self.personArray objectAtIndex:pathChosen.row];
    NSLog(@"the row selected is %@",personObject);


    self.addNewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    self.addNewController.personObject = self.personObject;
     self.addNewController.personObject = self.personObject;

    self.personObject.firstName = addNewController.firstNametxt.text;
    NSLog(@"the row selected is %@",addNewController.firstNametxt.text);
   //its giving me a null value here for addnewcontroller.firstNametxt.text.




}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really clean up your code, man. There are duplicated lines one just below the other. You will have to work with more accuracy and concentration if you want to code successfully without going crazy.

Your assignment statement should be the other way round. A trivial mistake that I am sure you could have caught yourself.

```
addNewController.firstNametxt.text = self.personObject.firstName;
```

By the way, if this does not work it is because maybe your `addNewController` has not yet created its text fields. Better to do the filling of text fields in the controller it self, best in the method `viewDidLoad`. The `personObject` which you defined as a property would be available for that.